# How to By-pass Emailing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am New to laravel. I got a live project(ERP) to setup locally on my PC with full functionality. but I want to by-pass emailing so that the transaction done locally can not be reflected to the clients.
Is there any code, so that if any activity related to email failed continue to next statement instead of showing "Whoops! Something went Wrong" or any kind of Error.

Comment: You can use try-catch to prevent error. And for checking server is on local-deployment , you can use APP_ENV=local varible from .env file

Comment: i have done with changing .env file.

MAIL_DRIVER=
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
MAIL_FROM_NAME=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your mail driver to [log](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#mail-and-local-development) in the .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=log
```